# I want to shorten or somehow improve my assembly program

Tags: assembly, arm

i have created an assembly program that prints integers from 1 to 1000 without printing multiples of 5. it works fine but i would like to somehow shorten my code or make it better in any way possible. i am new to assembly and this is my first time creating a program using ARMsim.

```
.equ SWI_PrStr, 0x69
.equ SWI_PrInt, 0x6b
.equ StDout, 1
.equ SWI_EXIT, 0x11

.global _start
start:

MOV R5, #1
MOV R6, #1
MOV R7, #1000

LOOPHERE:

CMP R5, R7
BLE LOOPBODY
B LOOPDONE

LOOPBODY:

CMP R6, #5
BLT LOOPIF
MOV R6, #0
B LOOPNEXT

LOOPIF:

MOV R0, #StDout
MOV R1, R5
swi SWI_PrInt

ldr R1, =EOL
swi SWI_PrStr

B LOOPNEXT

LOOPNEXT:

ADD R5, R5, #1
ADD R6, R6, #1
B LOOPHERE

LOOPDONE:
swi SWI_EXIT

.data

EOL: .asciz "\n"
.end
```

Comment: http://goo.gl/vcAk0D

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about improving a working piece of code. It might be suitable for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

The key is to use the conditional instructions that makes ARM assembly so different from other architectures.

```
start:
    mov    r0, #StDout
    mov    r5, #0       ;Main Counter
    mov    r4, #5       ;Modulo-5 counter
loop:
    add    r5, #1
    subs   r4, #1       ;Update counters
    moveq  r4, #5

    movne  r1, r5
    swine  SWI_PrInt    ;Print number if not multiple of 5
    ldrne  r1, =EOL
    swine  SWI_PrStr

    cmp    r5, #1000     ;Loop until we reach 1000
    bne    loop
```

Comment: I think this is a fantastic illustration of, to me, a hitherto unfamiliar feature. I vote to keep it!

Comment: line 6 gives me a syntax error, unexpcted # expecting ident

Comment: also line 16 is "unknown opcode or directive: brne"

Comment: Yeah, I meant bne, sorry for that. I don't see what is wrong with "add r3, #1" though, normally it should be a pseudo-op for "add r3, r3, #1" but there is no point in complicating it like that ^^

Comment: I also changed the registers to calle-saved registers in case the PrInt and PrStr would overwrite r2 and r3 (which they are allowed to)

Comment: Oh and this is wrong anyway since SWI_PrInt could modify the status flags (unless you use ARMv2 or earlier, which I doubt). It's in all case hard to write proper optimized assembly function if you rely on calling C library ones which have a rigid (and unpractical) calling convention.

Comment: @user2537102 Older (pre-UAL) assemblers use differing syntaxes for ARM and Thumb code - `add r3, #1` is Thumb syntax for what would be `adds r3, r3, #1` in ARM syntax. Only in UAL syntax is the 2-op form allowed as a shorthand for ARM-mode 3-op with Rd==Rn.